# Can I set the font size in the Document Map in Word 2008?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2008

Is there any way how to set font size in Document Map portion of Word 2008 (Mac) to something actually readable ? Or set different font?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the document for which you want to alter the size of the document map
entries. In the Styles pane, which you can display by pressing
Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S, click the Manage Styles button. On the Edit tab, locate
and click the Document Map style. Click the Modify button. In the Modify
Style dialog box, specify the desired font and size for the style. Click OK,
and then click Close to close the Manage Styles dialog box.

Comment: The instructions are for MS Word 2003 on Windows. They are not applicable starting with step 5 and onward

Comment: Edited original answer.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Fyi - Ctrl-Alt-Shift-S does not open Styles, locating the Document Map style and editing it did the trick. Must have missed the style first time.